# How to filter datatables with Select dropdowns

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

Have one Datatable and individual column filters available. Need to get filter with search box and filter with select dropdown. Tried with following code and it is working fine with search box filters and added select box filter code as well. But it is not filtering based on the select dropdown.

```
 this.dtTrigger.subscribe(() => {
  this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
    dtInstance.columns().every(function() {
      const that = this;
      $("select", this.footer()).on("keyup change", function() {
        if (that.search() !== this["value"]) {
          that.search(this["value"]).draw();
        }
      });
      $("input", this.footer()).on("keyup change", function() {
        if (that.search() !== this["value"]) {
          that.search(this["value"]).draw();
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

[image: Filter screenshtot reference]

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drop-down-population-t5ngwp)

Comment: Can you explain this bit more `get few columns can filter with search box` ?

Comment: If datatable columns contains dropdowns need to filter with select dropdowns, if no dropdowns need to filter with normal search box.

Comment: You have shown in red circle select box superman ? and inside demo in stackblitz theres no data loaded with the same/

Comment: Yes for reference I added the screenshot with text box.

Comment: So basically, you need to fill search select with all available data if drop down column available. And if not then in search text box we write superman.. Is it correct?

Comment: https://drop-down-population-joql41.stackblitz.io/ is this what you wanted to do ?

Comment: Dropdowns are missed in column levels, actually once we select check box dropdowns are enabled. In my requirement like only drop-downs available in the table. Need to filter based on dropdown values.

Comment: Okay.. after you clicked on checkbox, dropdown enabled inside column, then what are you doing inside that dropdown-column selects and what to do with table footer select filter ?